# Arithmetic overflow error when averaging/summing milliseconds

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Having a lot of trouble solving this (I looked through other posts with the same problem but unfortunately I didn't have much luck in applying proposed solutions to my situation).

I have a single (very large) table with transactional information. One of the columns is Transaction Execution Time (field type Time). Execution Time is usually <1 sec but it can go up to a couple of minutes.

Daily, Weekly, Monthly and Yearly transaction reports need to be available and they need to contain average transaction time. Due to large number of entries I am facing overflow when doing average/sum.

Here is a (simplified) sample I am using to test:

```
SELECT  
DATEPART (YEAR, TimeStamp) as 'Year',
COUNT(*) as 'Transaction count',
AVG((DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, '0:00:00',ExecutionTime))) as 'Average execution time',
SUM((DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, '0:00:00',ExecutionTime))) as 'Total execution time'
FROM RecordedTransactions
GROUP BY 
DATEPART (YEAR, TimeStamp)
```

What would be the best approach to solve the overflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`DATEDIFF_BIG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-big-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) instead of `DATEDIFF`:

> DATEDIFF_BIG ( datepart , startdate , enddate )
>
> This function returns the count (as a **signed big integer** value) of the specified datepart boundaries crossed between the specified startdate and enddate.

Answer (score 1):

Try instead ensuring that all of your datatypes are treated as a `BIGINT` rather than an `int`:

```
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, TimeStamp) AS Year,
       COUNT_BIG(*) AS [Transaction count],
       AVG((DATEDIFF_BIG(MILLISECOND, '0:00:00', ExecutionTime))) AS [Average execution time],
       SUM((DATEDIFF_BIG(MILLISECOND, '0:00:00', ExecutionTime))) AS [Total execution time]
FROM RecordedTransactions
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, TimeStamp);
```

`SUM` and `AVG` return the same datatype they were passed. `COUNT` returns an `int`, and `COUNT_BIG` returns a `bigint`. For `SUM`, this means that (as your query stands) if it surpasses 2,147,483,647, it'll fail. Using `DATEDIFF_BIG`, means that the value returned is a `bigint`, thus your `SUM` can return a value of up to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.